# /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, gitlab

I'm trying to install gitlab-ce on my raspberry pi 4B, 4GB model. My operating system is Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64bit.
Installer taken from [here](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/raspberry-pi2/packages/raspbian/buster/gitlab-ce_14.9.3-ce.0_armhf.deb)

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

Multiple failures occurred:
* Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed occurred in Chef Infra Client run: runit_service[gitlab-kas] (gitlab-kas::enable line 121) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ruby_block[restart_log_service] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/runit/libraries/provider_runit_service.rb line 65) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas/log ----
STDOUT: timeout: run: /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas/log: (pid 21560) 34s, got TERM
STDERR:
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas/log ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas/log returned 1
* Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed occurred in delayed notification: execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] (gitlab::gitlab-rails line 477) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '127'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear returned 127
* Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed occurred in delayed notification: runit_service[gitlab-kas] (gitlab-kas::enable line 121) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas ----
STDOUT: timeout: run: /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas: (pid 21561) 65s, got TERM
STDERR:
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/gitlab-kas returned 1
```

*Update: Distro info:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: What version of Raspberry Pi OS are you using? (run `cat /etc/*release` to see distro info)

Comment: @sytech Done update in original post. Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Comment: GitLab is only supported on buster for raspberry pi according to the docs, not bullseye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation scripts for the Raspberry Pi only work on debian *buster*. Notice the distro/version specified for the package is `raspbian/buster`:

[image: Distro package]

However, you have installed the newer *bullseye* version of raspbian:

> PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"

In order to use this install script, you'll need to use the [legacy debian buster release](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#:%7E:text=Debian%20version:%2010) for Raspberry PI OS.